# CSS - How to make moving transition animation responsive?

Tags: css, animation, responsive-design, css-transitions

I made a little animation, 5 images moving on a half cyclic path. For this motion I set some position values in percentage with a linear timing and it's working fine. The main problem is that it's not responsive at all, for smaller resolutions obviously the given percentages doesn't fit well. I want to make it work for different screen sizes. To have an idea this is a little snippet of the code:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.someimg{
    position:absolute;
    height: 19%;
    top:2.3%;
    left: 48%;
    transform:rotate(28deg);
    animation-name: img-animation;
    animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-delay:3.3s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    visibility:hidden;
}

@keyframes img-animation {
    0%   {
        visibility: visible;
        top:14%;
        left: 36.5%;    
    }

    50% {
        top:6%;
        left: 41%;
    }

    99% {
        visibility: hidden;
      }

    100% {
        top:2.3%;
        left: 48%;
        visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

My main question is, that is there some library or framework which I can use to make it responsive while the circles still can move? I though about Bootstrap but because of the movement I don't think that is possible. The only chance what I see to use media querys, but I'm open to any good practice / advice which can make my life easier. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you want it to look like on smaller screens?

Comment: I you end up with this, can you please accept my answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

I cant add comments, but I think you can create multiple `@keyframes`.
With that you can create `Media Queries` and based on screen width use different `@keyframes`

```
@media only screen and (min-width:568){
 .someimg{
   animation-name: img-animation2;
 }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width:768){
.someimg{
   animation-name: img-animation3;
 }
} 

@media only screen and (min-width:1024){
.someimg{
   animation-name: img-animation4;
 }
```

}

Comment: Yes, I thought about something similar, but I have to do it with like 7-8 images which have at least  4 keyframe points and with 3 different screen sizes 96 positioning at it will not be the best, so I remain at this solution only if I have to, but thank you for your answer I appreciate it :)

Comment: Maybe is somewhere any library that provides what you want, but I dont know about it, so.. :/